# How to set the current date as a title

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making a simple iOS notes application just to learn, and I wanted to add a simple date when the notes are created. Kinda like the default notes.app. This is what I have tried so far:

I have created a label in the storyboard and made it into a property and synthesized it. This is my code

```
- (void)configureCell:(IdeasTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ...

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
 NSDate *dateTmp;
cell.dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

It keeps returning an error... any ideas on what is causing the problem? Sorry, for the dumb question, but I have just started iOS dev.

Comment: You can look at the answers below to solve your crash.  You should also be aware that creating an `NSDateFormatter` is expensive.  You should create it once and store it in an instance variable.  Don't create a new one for every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a crash is that the NSDate* object is not initialized. You need to assign it an instance representing the current date:

```
NSDate *dateTmp = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! I know I was missing something!

Comment: still you are not able to get the date

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *dateTmp = [NSDate date];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp];
```

the above code gives me the proper result

Comment: ya...that's what I my code is with an extra line: `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`